# Integration of cloud hub with on premise splunk

Tags: mule, mule-component

In one of the requirement i want to integrate splunk with existing mule esb server that we are using(we are using cloudhub).
How can we achieve that?
Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Splunk connector](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/#!/splunk-integration-connector) to integrate within your applications. If you want to just send event data from existing applications see this other documentation page: [Sending Data from Runtime Manager to External Monitoring Software](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/sending-data-from-arm-to-external-monitoring-software)

Comment: I want to display logs coming from deployed cloudhub application to splunk.

Comment: You should open request in MuleSoft Support Center.

Answer (score 0):

Add below configuration in your log4j file.

```
<Configuration packages="com.mulesoft.ch.logging.appender,com.splunk.logging">

<Http name="SPLUNK" url="https://input-prd-p-3ppsrv6qrg3h.cloud.splunk.com:8088" token="19954BDA-7A21-4FFA-A1E5-B3DFB7C75D55" disableCertificateValidation="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m" />
        </Http>
```

where you should prefix "input-" to the domain name you have for splunk & the token will be the one that of http even collector.

Also while logging give reference of above http splunk appender :

```
<Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="SPLUNK" />
</Root>
```

Let me know if it works